# Is it possible in Maven to have more than one profile active at the same time, by default?

Tags: java, maven

I have the following profile setup in Maven:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <environment>prod</environment>
            <serverAddress>https://example.com/v1</serverAddress>
            <pubNubSubscribeKey>blah-blah</pubNubSubscribeKey>
            <sentryDsn>https://username:password@sentry.io/id</sentryDsn>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <environment>dev</environment>
            <serverAddress>http://localhost:8080/v1</serverAddress>
            <pubNubSubscribeKey>blah blah</pubNubSubscribeKey>
            <sentryDsn/>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>win32</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>Windows</family>
                <arch>x86</arch>
            </os>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>win64</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>Windows</family>
                <arch>amd64</arch>
            </os>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

There are four profiles but one of the two architectures and one of the two `prod`/`dev` profiles should be active at the same time. The `dev` profile is configured to be active by default, when `win64` gets active due to the activation criteria, the `dev` profile becomes inactive.

Is there a way to keep the `dev` profile active unless the `prod` profile becomes active?

In essence, I want a logic like this:

```
------------------------
|      | win32 | win64 |
------------------------
| dev  |       |   X   |
------------------------
| prod |       |       |
------------------------
```

I have an `application.properties` template in `src/main/resources` that looks something like this:

```
version=${version}
environment=${environment}
server.address=${serverAddress}
pubnub.keys.subscribe=${pubNubSubscribeKey}
sentry.dsn=${sentryDsn}
```

and then using a filter:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>application.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

I populate it with the correct value for either `prod` or `dev`. If that doesn't happen, the application fails to start. I cannot relay on my computer's `setting.xml` or an environment variable for `dev` to be active, because that means it won't be active on other computers and it would be very confusing.

Comment: I recommend to remove the profiles and create the appropriate artifacts if you really have those properties being packaged into the resulting artifacts which usually is not a good idea...another solution would be to use https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `activeByDefault` is a fallback that is activated if no other profile is activated.

To activate more than one profile, you could either add them in the `activeProfiles` section of your `settings.xml` - which kind of makes sense for local development to set the profile to `dev` or to `prod` on other machines.

You could trigger it with CLI parameters like the `-P` option or via System-Property-Activation and `-Dpropname=value`. The system property option has also a negative-version that triggers the profile if a property is either not-set or doesn't have a specific values. This could well be used to implement an either-or-switch, with the default being triggered if a property is not set:

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
       <property>
           <name>!prod</name> <!-- deactivated if system property prod is set, otherwise activated -->
       </property>
    </activation>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <activation>
       <property>
           <name>prod</name> 
       </property>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Deactivate dev/activate prod with

```
mvn ... -Dprod=true
```

Apart from these options, it seems there is no direct way of activating a profile unconditionally in combination with another profile that is triggered conditionally.

But there is a little workaround that activates a profile conditionally, with the condition always being true, and that is use the file activation and a file that always exists, like the `pom.xml` or - if your poms are located in a different position, `.` works as well

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
       <file>
           <exists>pom.xml</exists>
       </file>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Comment: On my computer, I need `dev` to be active unless I activate `prod`. Would either the hack or `activeProfiles` do that? The hack sounds like it would have both `dev` and `prod` active at the same time.

Comment: In that case I would activate it in the settings file and or activate it via unset system property, so as soon as you set the system property to prod, dev get's deactivated

Comment: If neither `dev` nor `prod` are enabled, the application doesn't start, which means by default, for new devs, it won't work and it'll be super confusing why it's not working.

Comment: no, the `<name>!prod</name>` (without value) activates the profile if _no_ property is set - which is the default, as soon as the property is set (i.e. on CLI), this profile is disabled and the prod profile is activate.

Comment: Surprisingly, using the `!prod` technique, ends with `dev` and `win64` active at the same time, which is exactly what I want, but calling `mvn -P prod help:active-profiles` ended up with `prod`, `dev` and `win64` all active at the same time.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I activate it and de-activate it with `-Dprod=true`

Comment: you have to trigger the prod profile via system property and not the `-P` option (to have the flip behavior): `mvn -Dprod=something help:active-profiles`, the actual value of the prod system property doesn't matter, just the that the property is set

Answer (score 1):

Profiles can also be activated based on the value of System properties.
You could have something like

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>win32</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>arch</name>
        <value>win32</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>environment</name>
        <value>dev</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>win64</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>arch</name>
        <value>win64</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>environment</name>
        <value>prod</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

now if you set two system properties like arch=win64 and environment=dev then you should have 2 active profiles

Comment: The problem here is that a new developer wouldn't have either `dev` nor `prod` enabled, so, the app wouldn't work for them and it would be very confusing.

Comment: @pupeno - In situations like that, a project should have some sort of README.txt or BUILD-HOWTO.txt indicating this requirement. A new user (or any user for that matter) is supposed to read such files when building for the first time (and every project should have one.)